# Change Duration on Out-of-Box Toast Duration

Tags: ui, toast

Is there a way to change the duration of an out-of-box toast message? The scenario is that I'm opening the edit page Specifically, the case message that says "Case xyz was saved" whenever the user opens the case in edit mode and saves the case - see below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Standard toasts are not customizable.